# Updating mysql database existing feild using php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert password to the database existing field.but this shows an error..

```
 <?php
    include './DB_Connection/connection.php';
    //some code
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE user_info SET password = '$password' WHERE company_name='$company_name' AND email = '$email' ");
            $result = $db->query($sql);
            echo 'out';
            if ($result) {//some cose
       }
    ?>
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in
>   "path"\password_generation.php on line 23

line 23 is : `$result = $db->query($sql);`

Comment: Use $result = mysql_query($sql);

Comment: Check if `$db` is an object having `query` method. e.g. `var_dump($db);`

Comment: The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: You are suing mysql_query to run the query and $db->query to get the result.Use mysql_query instead.

Comment: possible duplicate . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php

Answer (score 1):

```
  <?php
include './DB_Connection/connection.php';
//some code
 $sql = "UPDATE user_info ". "SET password = $password ". 
           "WHERE company_name = $company_name AND email= $email";
     $result=  mysql_query($sql)
      //  $result = $db->query($sql);
        echo 'out';
        if ($result) {//some cose
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove 'mysql_query' function, $db->query() should get a string.
and mysql_query is already deprecated in 5.5